# Colored box with image and text, no margins

Tags: margins, boxes

I would be extremely grateful to get some help with this following problem: 
I would like to have following outcome:

[image: Wished outcome]

Where the grey box is all the way out in the margin, but the image and the rest of the text in the document has a specific margin. I would also like to include a listing of text in the colored box.

Closest I can get is this:

```
\noindent
\fcolorbox{MyGray2}{MyGray2}{\parbox{\paperwidth-3.0\fboxsep-3.0\fboxrule}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1, left=5in]{cvbild.jpg}}{Hejhejhejhejhejhej akj kajhf kjhj hkdjfh skdjfh ksdjfg kdsg }}
```

However is the margin to the left still white and the text doesn't come even close to where I want it.

Another try was to make a `\mybox` and change the margins just over the box, but then I get a new page before and after the box.

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=MyGray2,
   % width=0.2\textwidth,   % this option controls the width of the box
    colupper=black,
    fontupper=\bfseries
}

\begin{document}  
\newgeometry{left=0in,right=0in} % set new margins  
\nopagebreak[4] % doesn't work  
\begin{mybox}  
\includegraphics[scale=.1, left]{cvbild.jpg}{example varfö alajlkejf ksdf }  
\end{mybox}  
\restoregeometry % restore margins
```

Comment: Have a look into the tcolorbox package

Comment: `\paperwidth-3.0\fboxsep-3.0\fboxrule}` is wrong as you want 2 not 3 presumably and either it should be `\textwidth` or you need to use `\hspace*{-\@oddsidemargin-1in}` so that the box starts flush to the paper edge not flush to the text area.

Answer (score 4):

One could use [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) or [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), for example, but this can also be done without those powerful packages using some boxes (for example, a `\makebox`, a `\parbox` of width equal to `\paperwidth`, a `\colorbox` and some `minipage`s for the inner contents); something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\par\medskip
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \colorbox{gray!30}{%
    \parbox{\paperwidth}{%
      \hspace*{\dimexpr\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}%
      \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{.05\textwidth}
        \mbox{}
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
        Some other text\par\bigskip
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        Email \\
        Phone \\
        Address
        \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
  }%
}\par\medskip

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I found this ansower very useful (for me)

Answer (score 3):

My answer uses `tcolorbox`. A macro `\mybox` is contructed which takes the picture file name and the text content as parameters. Also, `tcolorbox` options may be given.

I commented the following source code to help you to adapt the settings for your application:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\mybox}{ O{} m +m }{%
  enhanced,sidebyside,size=tight,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
  lower separated=false,fontlower=\sffamily,
  extrude left by=\dimexpr\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
  extrude right by=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-1in\relax,
  colback=gray!30,%               <-- color
  lefthand width=0.2\textwidth,%  <-- width of picture
  sidebyside gap=1cm,%            <-- distance between picture and text
  before skip=8pt,%               <-- space before
  after skip=8pt,%                <-- space after
  #1
}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}\tcblower #3}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\mybox{photo.png}
{
  Listet text here\par\bigskip
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  Email    & a@b.com\\
  Phone    & 555 666\\
  Address  & Green Lane, Hometown
  \end{tabular}
}

\lipsum[3]

% Example: optionally adapt picture width
\mybox[lefthand width=0.3\textwidth]
  {example-image-a.png}
{
  Listet text here\par\bigskip
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  Email    & a@b.com\\
  Phone    & 555 666\\
  Address  & Green Lane, Hometown
  \end{tabular}
}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I just used a stack.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}\def\stackalignment{l}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx, lipsum}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\lipsum[1]
\noindent\addstackgap{\stackon[0pt]{%
   \makebox[\textwidth]{\textcolor{blue!10}{\rule{1.01\paperwidth}{6\baselineskip}}}%
}{%
  \includegraphics[width=1.1in,height=6\baselineskip]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{.5in}%
  \raisebox{.7\baselineskip}{\Longstack{Listed text here\\ \\Email\\Phone\\Address}}%
}}
\noindent Margins here for the rest of the text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fill=gray!20, right, 
      text height=5\baselineskip, 
      text width=\paperwidth,
      yshift=-2.2in  % top margin++
      ] at (current page.north west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{image}}\hspace*{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}\sffamily
list\\[\baselineskip]name\\tel\\email
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```